# Recursive Algorithm for Linked List in C

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

I have a structure which I name passengers, which is sorted in alphabetical order, and I **copy** it to a linked list with the same elements as structure.
What would be the best algorithm to reverse the order of the elements of the list, so that I can print it out in alphabetical order easily? Now of course my printing doesn't work if the first value it encounters is NULL

```
typedef struct               
{
    char fullname[40];
    unsigned short phonenr[10]; 
    unsigned int seatnr;        
}PASSENGERS;       


typedef struct list1
{
    char fullname[40];
    struct list1 *next;
}LIST1;

int main()
{
    selectsortnm(passenger); /*A function I use to sort alphabetically*/
    LIST1 *list1, *start=NULL;
    int i=0;
    while (strcmp(passenger[i].fullname,"\0")!=0);
    {
        list1 = (LIST1 *) malloc (sizeof(LIST1));
        list1->next = NULL;
        strcpy(list1->fullname,passenger[i].fullname);
        if (start ==NULL)
        {
            start = list1;
            i++;
        }
        else 
        {
            list1->next = start;
            start = list1;
            i++;
        }
    }

    //Recursive algorithm

    LIST1 *current = list1;
    while (current !=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s",current->fullname);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Also what is LIST1 ?  Please share code that can be understood easily.

Comment: We need a linked-list.stackoverflow.com so we can filter out half of the incoming questions.

Comment: Using a doubly linked list would do the trick by traversing it backwards. Also (this is more like workaround) you could traverse the `passengers` array backwards when creating the list, but you would need 2 loops: 1 to get last index (the last record whose _fullname_ is not `NULL`), and the 2nd: looping from the index found by previous loop to _0_. Hmm, but there's recursivity in neither 2 approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone, I am pretty new at this, but no excuses for this..

Comment: I added some more information to my code!

Comment: So, did you get any error or something in your code?

Comment: No, as the question states I would like to know if there is an optimal way to reverse the linked list! The code works, but it doesn't print out anything because it finds NULL in the first element..

Comment: The code after `//Recursive algorithm` is not recursive.

Comment: I am seconding @jxh. Your 'recursive' code is *iterative*, not *recursive*. Recursion does result in reverse traversal of a singly linked list (if you wait for the recursion to return before printing).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a singly linked list, indeed recursive traversal will print it in reverse order...if the stack has enough space of course:

```
void printListRev(struct LIST *p)
{
    if (!p) return;
    printListRev(p->next);
    printf("%s\n", p->data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a recursive algorithm to reverse your list. You can just change how you are inserting into your list.

This is how you are inserting items into your list:

```
        list1 = make_list_item_from(passengers[i]);
        list1->next = start;
        start = list1;
        i++;
```

Assuming `passengers` is sorted, inserting at the front of the list results in a list that is in reverse of the order of passengers.

To counter this, you can walk `passengers` backwards as you insert into your list. Alternatively, you can maintain a reference to the last item of the list, and add your new items to the end of your list.